# Vaadin, war, tomcat - production mode - javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable

Tags: gradle, vaadin, tomcat9

I build Vaadin project in production mode by gradle.

Here build.gradle.kts

```
plugins {
    kotlin("jvm") version "1.3.20"
    id("com.github.johnrengelman.shadow") version "4.0.3"
    id("com.devsoap.vaadin-flow") version "1.0"
    id("org.gretty") version "2.3.1"
    id("war")
}

val kotlinVersion = "1.3.20" //by extra("1.3.20")
val jettyVersion = "9.4.14.v20181114"
val vaadinVersion = "12.0.4"

val jettyDep = { dep: String, suffix: String ->
    "org.eclipse.jetty${if (suffix.isNotEmpty()) ".$suffix" else suffix}:$dep:$jettyVersion"
}

vaadin.autoconfigure()

vaadin {
    setProductionMode(true)
}

dependencies {
    implementation(kotlin("stdlib-jdk8"))
    implementation("com.github.jengelman.gradle.plugins:shadow:4.0.3")
    implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:$kotlinVersion")
    implementation("com.vaadin:vaadin-bom:$vaadinVersion")
    implementation("com.vaadin:vaadin-core:$vaadinVersion")
    //implementation("com.vaadin:flow-server-production-mode:1.4.0") // Switch to production mode
    implementation("com.github.mvysny.karibudsl:karibu-dsl-v10:0.6.2")
    implementation("ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.2.3")
    implementation("javax.servlet:javax.servlet-api:3.1.0")
    implementation(jettyDep("jetty-plus", ""))
    implementation(jettyDep("jetty-continuation", ""))
    implementation(jettyDep("jetty-server", ""))
    implementation(jettyDep("websocket-server", "websocket"))
    implementation(jettyDep("javax-websocket-server-impl", "websocket"))
    implementation("com.auth0:java-jwt:3.7.0")
    implementation("org.reflections:reflections:0.9.11")

}
```

Success create production mode war by command:

```
gradlew assemble
```

Nice.
But when I deploy war to Tomcat 9 I get error:

```
18-Mar-2019 19:23:07.310 INFO [main] org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-nio-8009"]
18-Mar-2019 19:23:07.314 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load Server initialization in [831] milliseconds
18-Mar-2019 19:23:07.342 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal Starting service [Catalina]
18-Mar-2019 19:23:07.342 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.16]
18-Mar-2019 19:23:07.368 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [D:\Programs\apache-tomcat-9.0.16\webapps\booking-sailero-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war]
19:23:28.496 [main] DEBUG org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging to Logger[org.eclipse.jetty.util.log] via org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
19:23:28.506 [main] INFO org.eclipse.jetty.util.log - Logging initialized @22304ms to org.eclipse.jetty.util.log.Slf4jLog
18-Mar-2019 19:23:32.302 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
 javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
        at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:200)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5125)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:713)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:690)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:695)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:978)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1850)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWARs(HostConfig.java:773)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:427)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1577)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:309)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:123)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setStateInternal(LifecycleBase.java:424)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.setState(LifecycleBase.java:367)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:929)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:831)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1377)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1367)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
        at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:902)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:423)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:928)
        at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:638)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:350)
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:492)

18-Mar-2019 19:23:32.307 SEVERE [main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal Context [/booking-sailero-1.0-SNAPSHOT] startup failed due to previous errors
18-Mar-2019 19:23:32.338 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [D:\Programs\apache-tomcat-9.0.16\webapps\booking-sailero-1.0-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [24,969] ms
18-Mar-2019 19:23:32.340 INFO [main] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [D:\Programs\apache-tomcat-9.0.16\webapps\karibu10-helloworld-application.war]
18-Mar-2019 19:23:34.874 INFO [main] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enab
```

Comment: This looks like Tomcat configuration problem. Tomcat 9 supports WebSockets, so that should not be the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I would assume the Jetty entries in your `dependencies` list causes Jetty classes to end up into the `.war` and thus also on the classpath. Some of those classes have some generic Servlet API annotations that are picked up by Tomcat, which tries to initialize them during server startup.

Comment: so is there a workaround for this. Can we tell tomcat to not scan those jars ?

Comment: Why do you have Jetty as a dependency when you're deploying to Tomcat?

Comment: Our application uses both jetty and tomcat servers internally for different purposes. All these jars are on the classpath and this causes "Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable". Issue started only recently after upgrading to jetty 9.

Comment: I did ask a question about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73557761/jetty-9-and-tomcat-9-jars-on-the-same-classpath