# Eclipse Jetty 9 and Apache Tomcat 9 JAR on the same classpath

Tags: java, tomcat, jetty, embedded-jetty, jetty-9

Fortunately or unfortunately our application uses both Eclipse Jetty and Apache Tomcat servers internally for different purposes. All these jars are on the same classpath and this causes "Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable" as below

```java
INFO: No global web.xml found
org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error during ServletContainerInitializer processing
javax.servlet.ServletException: Not running on Jetty, JSR-356 support unavailable
    at org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.onStartup(WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.java:271)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5166)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.startInternal(StandardHost.java:843)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1384)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1374)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.InlineExecutorService.execute(InlineExecutorService.java:75)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.startInternal(ContainerBase.java:909)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.startInternal(StandardEngine.java:262)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.startInternal(StandardService.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.startInternal(StandardServer.java:930)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Tomcat.start(Tomcat.java:486)
```

Issue only started after upgrading to Eclipse Jetty 9. Removing Eclipse Jetty's JARs is not an option because we need them as well. Please help!

Comment: I'm impressed that this ever ran.  Why do you have to upgrade?  It sounds like you had it as stable as it was going to get before.  I'd leave it alone.  You're going to be playing with class loading forever to get this to work.

Comment: It was running on jetty 8.1 previously, had to upgrade to support websocket related stuff for jetty apps.

Comment: This might be a good time to look at splitting it into two.  While Tomcat [supports websockets](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/web-socket-howto.html) too if you've got Jetty specific code you could create a micro service architecture to handle that and JEE standard code for the rest.

Comment: Thanks for taking time to respond to this. So is there no way to get around this with minimal changes ?

Comment: Honestly it's a bit difficult to tell.  The Jetty code is seeing that the underlying websocket implementation is Tomcat and it doesn't like that.  There is implementation configuration in lib/tomcat-websocket.jar in the META-INF/services directory.  I haven't tried to do what you're doing though.

Comment: I don't see any tomcat-websocket.jar. I do see spring-websocket.jar though